# Non-existence of a non-negative function s.t. $\int_0^1f^n(x)dx \to 2$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, continuity, riemann-integration

Question: Prove that there does not exist a non-negative continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^1f^n(x)dx \to 2 $ as $n \to \infty$.

Attempt:

Case 1: $\sup f(x) \leq 1 \implies \sup f^n(x) \leq 1$.

$\int_0^1f^n(x)dx\leq 1 \not\to 2$ as $n\to \infty$.

Case 2: $1<\sup f(x) \implies 1< \sup f^n(x)$

By the property of continuous functions on closed intervals, $\exists \ c\in[0,1]$ , such that $f(c)=\sup f $ and $\exists \ \delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in[c-\delta,c+\delta]\cap [0,1]$, $1<k \leq f(x)$ for some $k$. Now, if $c$ is interior to $[0,1]$, $\delta$ can be taken such that $[c-\delta,c+\delta]\subset[0,1]$. For the boundary points, we take $[c,c+\delta]$ or $[c-\delta,c]$.

So, $  \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}k^ndx=2\delta k^n \leq \int_0^1f^n(x)dx$.

Fixing $\delta$, we can take $n\to \infty$ which results in $2\delta k^n\to \infty $.

So, in either cases, $\int_0^1f^n(x)dx \not\to 2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Is this correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Comment: Yes, what you have is correct. You can also prove this using Cauchy Schwartz. By CS, $\left(\int_0^1 f^n dx\right)^2 \le \int_0^1 f^{2n} dx$. If limit equals to $2$, then by taking limit on both sides, one get $4 = 2^2 \le 2$ which is absurd.

Comment: You are correct. Note that $f$ does not exist even without the non-negativity assumption. Just take $n=2k$.

Comment: @RobertZ I think the statement is true for bounded Lebesgue integrable functions too, right?

Comment: @Szeto Yes, see achille hui's approach.